# Why is the default exported component is giving no-undef error in React JS?

Tags: reactjs

I'm a beginner in React so trying to get hands on the language. But I'm getting the below error while compiling my code.

[image: Error]

Below are the code of my Person and App components

**Person Component:**

```
import React from 'react';

const person = () => {
    return <p>I'm a person</p>;
}

export default Person;
```

**App Component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Person from './Person/Person';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>I'm a React App</h1>
        <Person/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React from 'react';

const person = () => {
    return <p>I'm a person</p>;
}

export default Person;
```

You  have a typo here: your component's name should start with a capital letter (here you named it `person`, but it should be `Person`, as a component name always start with a capital), so in order to fix it you have to write it like this:

```
const Person = () => {
    return <p>I'm a person</p>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will fix it. I've one doubt regarding changing the name of the function in the Person Component. If we change the Person component code like below and want to use it in the App component. Can we do it? If yes, then how?

import React from 'react';

export const test = () => {
    return <p>I'm a person</p>;
}

Comment: when you write const MyComponent = () => {...}, the name of your component is MyComponent. So this is the object that you have to export (when you do export default MyComponent), and what you can use somewhere else with <MyComponent />

Comment: If I have helped, could you consider marking this answer as accepted? Thanks

Comment: For doing it, you have to click on the check icon, saying "Accept this answer if it solved my problem"
If you have others problem, I'll be glad to help you!